# вытащить подстроку из строки regex js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Вообщем нашел паттерн, для проверки Российского номера

```
/^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}$/gm
```

Она работает в тестерах. Когда ввожу реальные номера. Но вырезать из строки номер - не получается.
У меня есть строка, например

```
let myStr = "Привет, вот мой номер +79994441632";
let pattern = /^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}$/gm;
console.dir(myStr.match(pattern));
```

Выводится null.
Номер выводится лишь только тогда, когда я все удаляю кроме самого номера(а нафиг оно мне так не нужно), мне нужно парсить номер из строки. Подскажите, как реализовать?
Вот так все работает

```
let myStr = "+79994441632";
let pattern = /^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}$/gm;
console.dir(myStr.match(pattern));
```

Output:

```
Array (1) [
"+79994441632"
]
```

Подскажите плиз, я уже и функции разные пробовал (matchAll, test, exec), не помогает.

Comment: Уберите ```^``` и ```$``` в начале и в конце регулярки

Comment: Если просто убрать, появится вероятность, что что-то похожее будет вырезаться изнутри более длинный последовательностей цифр.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в начале и конце регулярки стоят символы начала и конца строки `^` и `$`, поэтому регулярка совпадает лишь со строками, содержащими только номер. Эти символы можно заменить на проверки, гарантирующие, что перед и после номера нет других цифр:

```js
let myStr = "Привет, вот мой номер +79994441632";
let pattern = /(?<!\d)(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}(?!\d)/gm;
console.dir(myStr.match(pattern));
```